# Use account balance only for billing agreement?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

When setting up a billing agreement for reference transaction purposes, I am being forced to choose a preferred payment method or to add a new CC if no payment methods are associated with the account during agreement setup.

Is there any way to allow a billing agreement to be setup to use only the account balance and not require an additional bank account or CC to be selected?

Answer (score 1):

It's going to require that something be setup as a backup funding source to the PayPal balance.

If you're really that worried about adding a bank account / credit card to the PayPal account, open up a separate "internet account" at the bank, and get a debit card for that account.

Then add that account and the debit card to the PayPal account.

This way the PayPal account won't have access to any bank account where you actually keep most of your money, but you won't be limited with what you can do with PayPal payments.